Laravel maintenence mode timestamp?
Does anyone know an easy way to get a timestamp of when your laravel app is put into maintenance mode? I want to display a message on my view which says "last updated xxxxx"

Which version of laravel you are using?

8, but upgrading to 10 in a couple weeks

For 10, it creates the file storage/framework/down, so you can always check for the existence of that file and get the timestamp on it

For Laravel 8:
Once you run artisan down you'll find a maintenance.php in storage/framework. You can utilize this file to get the last modified date and display it. Be aware, that this file is not updated if you run artisan down again if your application is already in maintenance mode.
